# Get the currency unit of a symbol Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

To retrieve the gold price from Yahoo Finance, I simply need to do:

```
web.get_data_yahoo("GC=F")
```

How do I get the currency unit? In this case, I would like "USD"; or even better "USD/ounce".
For crude oil, it would be "USD"; or even better "USD/barrel".

Thanks

Comment: If you're using `pandas` (I assume so by the `get_data_yahoo()` function), can you please tag as such?

Comment: I think pandas_datareader does not have such a function. You could scrape the currency info from the Yahoo website.

Answer (score 3):

```
# pip install yfinance
import yfinance as yf

gold = yf.Ticker("GC=F")

print(gold.info['currency'])
```

Result:

`USD`

Comment: Thanks. Too bad I cannot get "USD per ounce". This is crazy that "ounce" is not mentioned in info!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Because of the `yfinance` new library:

Latest (yfinance==0.2.31)

```
gold = yf.Ticker("GC=F")
print(gold.history_metadata['currency'])  # returns: USD
```

The previous one gives an error when running:

```
print(gold.info['currency'])
raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v6/finance/quoteSummary/GC=F?modules=financialData&modules=quoteType&modules=defaultKeyStatistics&modules=assetProfile&modules=summaryDetail&ssl=true
```